# How to check whether the data is saved to Firebase or is in Queue?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am Sending a message and Want to Show the Message as Queued if the Message has Not Got Stored to Firebase database and is not accessible to the others client and after it get stored to the Firebase database, I want to change the Status to saved.

Let me know how I can achieve this design.

I tried using 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41778277/check-whether-the-firebase-data-has-been-committed, but did not succeed.

My Code

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        if (check == 1) {

            String temp_key = db.push().getKey();
            message_root = db.child(temp_key);

            message_root.child("Text").setValue(chatmessage.getText().toString());

            message_root.child("sender_name").setValue(current_user.replace("@zumi.com", ""));

            message_root.child("sender_photo").setValue("");

            message_root.child("timestamp").setValue(mydate);

            message_root.child("message_status").setValue("Queued", new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
                    message_root.child("message_status").setValue("Saved");
                }
            });

            chatmessage.setText("");


        } else {

        }
    }
});
```

I am Getting an Error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.cosmic.zumi_test, PID:
>   25109 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to parse
>   node with class class

Also, that data gets stored to Firebase without the `Message_status` field.

Comment: A completion listener as in the linked question would accomplish that. If it doesn't work for you, share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks Looking into this...I have added the Minimal Code and error which I got...

Comment: What line raises that exception?

Comment: message_root.child("message_status").setValue("Queued", new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
                    message_root.child("message_status").setValue("Saved");
                }
            }); ...This is the Line which Raises the Exception

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  thanks ...I got the Solution to Error... instead of using DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() ... i was just using Firebase.CompletionListener()...Anyway Thanks ....

Comment: Good to hear this was solved Akshay. Mixing Firebase SDK versions is a sure way to cause problems. Can somebody cast a close-vote as non-reproducible?